# Why is my <path> line not appearing on my d3 line chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Why is my line not appearing on my linechart ?

I am trying to use d3 to create a line chart, with two y-axis and one x-axis.
However when i try and append a line to my graph i get the error message.

`d3.v5.min.js:2 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "function a(a){va…".`

which I assume is the `d3.line()` not returning a valid "M" command.

Below is:

My js fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/ryboh1/z5xvj7ou/2/

Where I think the bug is happening

```
 svg.append("path")
      .datum(covidLine)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", (d,i) =>{

        let lines = createLine.y(d => yScaleCovid(d[1][i]))
        .x(d => xScaleDates( d[0][i] ))

        return lines
      }
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

The line generator needs the x and y defining, in this case to be your date and covidCase, eg

```
let createLine = d3.line()
.y(data => yScaleCovid(data["covidCases"]))
.x(data => xScaleDates(data["dates"]))
```

Secondly, the array needs to be arranged so each element in the array represents a point on the line, for example:

```
let covidLine = []

dates.forEach(function(d,i){
  let obj = {}
  obj.dates = d
  obj.covidCases = covidCases[i]
  covidLine.push(obj)
})
```

And lastly, the creation of the line can be simply called as such:

```
svg.append("path")
  .datum(covidLine)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr("d", createLine)
```

This is an updated version of your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lj6o31n8/